# MSSQL INSERT EVENT and catch event with php

Tags: php, sql-server, events, insert

i've a question about MSsql server (running on windows server) and linux web server with php (other server).

Is it possible to catch insert event in mssql database via php on remote web server?

My focus is to eliminate polling on mssql table from php.

There is a better solution to  call, from  `MSSQL INSERT EVENT`, an external remote script (not only php).

Thanks Matteo.

Comment: The short answer is "no". The SQL Server instance is aware of what's being changed, and you can add logic to the SPs you are using, or create triggers to do *X* on the event on those objects, but a entirely different server and application has no clue what SQL Server is "doing" or being told.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Thanks best regards.